# Effect to reveal the text from left to right in pure css

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I would like to create a effect to reveal to text like my codesandbox. Instead of using animation mask-image, do I have any other option?

```css
.animation-text-wipe {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to left,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 75%,
    #000 75%
  );
  -webkit-mask-size: 500%;
}

.animation-text-wipe.animate-in {
  animation-name: text-wipe;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes text-wipe {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-mask-position: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-mask-position: 0%;
  }
}
.text {
  width: 60%;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ffff;
}

.app {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="App">
      <div class="text-animations">
        <div class="animate-in animation-text-wipe">
          <div class="text">
            <span> i am label </span>
            <input />
            <span> i am label </span>
            <input />
            <span> i am label </span>
            <input />
            <span> i am label </span>
            <input />
            <p>
              real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune
              protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops
              off after two months or so, although protection against severe
              disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
              from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England
              Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated
              people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study
              from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and showed antibody
              levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine "especially among
              men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons
              with immunosuppression." Vaccines may have prevented a
              quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors
              Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and
              39,000 deaths among seniors "We conducted this prospective
              longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba
              Medical Center, a large tertiary medical center in Israel,"
              Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The
              researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies
              -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection --
              correlate with protection against infection, but for this study
              they studied only antibody levels.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-carlos-0jvhq)

Comment: What effect are you aiming for? And is there a problem with your current method?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I look for reveal the text effect like my codesandbox. But wondering if there is any better solution instead of using mask

Comment: @Paulie_D I included my codesandbox in description

Comment: @Paulie_D understand. update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body:not(.App) {
  background-color: red;
}

.App {
  background-color: white;
}

.text::before {
  content: '';
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: reveal;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  right: 0;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  0% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* First second. */
  20% {
    width: 88%;
  }
  /* Second second. */
  40% {
    width: 76%;
  }
  /* Third second. */
  60% {
    width: 64%;
  }
  /* Fourth second. */
  80% {
    width: 52%;
  }
  /* Fifth second. */
  100% {
    width: 40%;
  }
}

.text {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class='App'>
    <div class='text-animations'>
      <div class='animate-in animation-text-wipe'>
        <div class='text'>
          <span> i am label </span>
          <input />
          <span> i am label </span>
          <input />
          <span> i am label </span>
          <input />
          <span> i am label </span>
          <input />
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops off after two months or so, although protection against severe disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies,
            from Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel covered 4,800 health care workers and
            showed antibody levels wane rapidly after two doses of vaccine 'especially among men, among persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with immunosuppression.' Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000
            deaths among seniors Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors 'We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large tertiary
            medical center in Israel,' Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense against infection -- correlate with protection
            against infection, but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: question why we have rule `.App {
  background-color: red;
}`. how can I make red background to reveal complete before all text is finished revealed under animation?

Comment: Do you want the background to be red or not? I'm not sure what you mean with: *How can I make red background to reveal complete before all text is finished revealed under animation?*

Comment: Yes I want background red display before the text reveal

Comment: So whatever the text is not reveal the background red should display

Comment: I updated my answer. Like this? Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: so I would like to have the text only applied 60% width for all and animation `reveal` applied with the text reveal with time. which mean if animation duration is 5s to applied 60% width of text. first second only applied 12% width( 60%/5), next second, 24%(60% / 5 + 60% /5) etc

Comment: same effect like I use `transition: width 0.5s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;`. but when I use transition I do not have the same effect like reveal text by using animation

Comment: I updated my answer. Now 60% width is revealed in 5s.

Comment: thank you. but the area without reveal text should display the background color red

Comment: You mean everything except `.App` should have a red background?

Comment: yap...so with the revealing text, background color red should display

Comment: I updated my answer. Is it okay now?